# Нахождение элемента в списке из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Словарь хранит ключи и значения в виде списков. Как получать список из такого словаря, чтобы искать вхождения какого-либо объекта в нём?

```
dic1 = {'key': ['val1', 'val2']}
dicList = ['val1', 'val2']
print(dic1.values())
print(dicList)
a = 'val2'
if a in dic1.values():
    print('in dictionary')
if a in dicList:
    print('in list')
```

Вывод:

```
dict_values([['val1', 'val2']])
['val1', 'val2']
in list
```

UPD:
Словаь и список даны для демонастрации того, что поиск вхождения с помощью `in` здесь подходит только для списка. Вопрос состоит в том как искать нахождение объекта `a` внутри словаря, а не сравнивать с приведённым в примере списком. Как найти вхождение `a` в словаре по аналогии с нахождением в списке?

**Вопрос:** **Как искать вхождение `a` внутри словаря?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dic1 = {'key': ['val1', 'val2'],
        'key2': ['val???',],
        'key3': ['xxx',]}

dicList = ['val1',
           'val???',
           'val2']

for k, v in dic1.items():
    for s in v:
        print("{:>4}/{:7} {:>3} {}".format(k, s, 'Yes', dicList) if s in dicList else "{:>4}/{:7} {:>3} {}".format(k, s, 'No', dicList))


key3/xxx      No ['val1', 'val???', 'val2']
 key/val1    Yes ['val1', 'val???', 'val2']
 key/val2    Yes ['val1', 'val???', 'val2']
key2/val???  Yes ['val1', 'val???', 'val2']
```

Comment: Так ведь проблема не в нахождении по ключу, а в том как искать вхождения внутри списка

Comment: я обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Да, Ваш код действительно работает. Только задача была, повторюсь, в нахождении конкретного эл-а как объект "a" в вопросе. Но код полностью объясняет как это сделать.